# jQuery autocomplete support in console window (chrome and mozilla browsers)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, console, mozilla, developer-tools

can anyone noticed and knows that working with mozilla console javascript and jquery autocomplete works perfectly [1](http://i.snag.gy/AeR26.jpg), but in chrome console it works only with basic javascript functions [2](http://i.snag.gy/RMF1y.jpg) and no jquery support. Can anyone provide any chrome extension, or reasonable answer of this kind of bug? (images added with numbers)

Answer (score 0):

That 'mozilla console' is actually Firebug console, get [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/) for Google Chrome to achieve similar functionality. Enjoy!

Comment: No. There doesn't work display for autocomplete functions at all, but autocomplete with tab suggests only the same functions as in default chrome console.